# Create Dropdown in button click and get selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having one Dropdown, one Textbox & one button in PHP & HTML. I am able to get Value of Selected Value of Dropdown as well as the value of Textbox by the button click. Here is my `index.html` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="function.php" method="post">
            <!-- here start the dropdown list -->
            <div id="mainContainer">
                <select name="dowpdown">
                    <option value="String">String</option>
                    <option value="Number">Number</option>
                </select>
                Enter first number <input type="text" name="fnum"/><hr/>

                <input type="submit" name="show_dowpdown_value" value="show"/>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php include("function.php"); ?>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Here is my `function.php` code:

```
<?php
 // here starts the php
 if (isset($_POST['show_dowpdown_value'])) {

    echo $_POST['dowpdown']; // this will print the value if downbox out
    $x=$_POST['fnum'];
    echo $_POST['fnum'];
}
?>
```

Now I have added another button that will generate one dropdown & one textbox on each click. Here is my code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(btn) {         
        var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
        var table = parentRow.parentNode;
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        //var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        var element2 = document.createElement("select");
        //element2.type = "select";
        var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.innerHTML = "Option1";
        option1.value = "1";
        element2.add(option1, null);
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.innerHTML = "Option2";
        option2.value = "2";
        element2.add(option2, null);
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }
</script>
```

It is generating the dropdown & textbox perfectly. But I am not able to get the values from those generated dropdown & textbox. Need help to get values from all dropdowns & textboxes on a single button click.

Comment: You need to add the `name` property to the HTML elements you are creating at run time and use this name to read it's data in PHP.

Comment: I modified the script like this - 

element1.name = "fnum";

element2.name = "dowpdown"

It is only returning value of Last Dropdown & Textbox.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. For getting all the values, the `name` should be unique. For e.g `fnum1`, `fnum2`, etc.

Comment: Or make the names an array and loop through them

Comment: As it is impossible to guess how many times the user will click the button, it is hard to set a unique name for each. How to make the names an array and loop through them? Any sample code, please.